# rclone move folder to folder in digitalocean spaces

Tags: digital-ocean, rclone

I'm using rclone with centos. I moved my files in my spaces. (160k totally) and i want to move my folders to another folder in space.

I try this command:

```
rclone move spaces:mycdn/tester spaces:mycdn/testerin
```

it doesn't work and gives me:

```
ERROR : : Entry doesn't belong in directory "" (same as directory)
```

thank you.

Comment: i did it with s3cmd.

Comment: s3cmd mv --recursive s3://bucket/tester s3://bucket/testerin/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move the files in a folder inside the same spaces you can try it from digitalocean spaces console as like the below images shows

[image]